# Wordpress media uploader: Upload Files font color is white. How to change?

Tags: wordpress

How could we change the font color of the tab in Wordpress media uploader? User unable to see the menu as its white.

As stackoverflow doesn't allow to insert image directly to the post as it requires at least 10 reputation.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jz5O.png)

Comment: Do you use any theme?

Comment: This looks like a theme or plugin issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WordPress 5.4, if you use your browser's inspector, you can see that the CSS class for the tab is called ".media-router .media-menu-item".

So you should be able to "overwrite" the applied CSS with adding custom CSS like this:

```
function custom_media_uploader_tab_color() {
  echo '<style>
    .media-router .media-menu-item {
      color: black !important;
    } 
  </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_media_uploader_tab_color');
```

Comment: I manage to add custom css in Elementor  

`.media-router .media-menu-item {    color: black !important;  
    } `

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Tokant

I manage to add custom css in Elementor

```
.media-router .media-menu-item {
      color: black !important;
    }
```