# Wordpress database query results not displaying

Tags: database, wordpress

So, I'm creating a Wordpress plugin which, when activated, creates a new table in the database and then stores entries from a form into that table.

The form submission is working perfectly and entries are successfully storing in the table.

Now I'm trying to create a shortcode which will retrieve a list of all the entries from the table and display them in a dropdown menu so that the use can select which entry to view.

The query to retrieve the data from the table appears to be working, but the "foreach" loop is not populating the dropdown list.

Here is a screenshot of the table contents:
[image]

And here is the code for the shortcode:

```
function cpe_history_select(){
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  $user_id = $current_user->ID;
  global $wpdb;
  $history_tbl = $wpdb->prefix . "cpe_history";
  $history_query = "SELECT id,submitDate FROM $history_tbl WHERE userID=$user_id ORDER BY submitDate DESC";
  $cpe_history = $wpdb->get_results ( $history_query );
  if(!empty($cpe_history)){
    $output = '<form action="" method="post">';
    $output .= '<select id="cpe_history" name="cpe_history">';
      $output .= '<option value="">Select</option>';
      foreach($cpe_history as $cpe_entry){
        $entry_id = $cpe_entry->id;
        $entry_date = $cpe_entry->submitDate;
        $ouput .= '<option value="' . $entry_id . '">' . $entry_date . '</option>';
      }
    $output .= '</select>';
    $output .= '</form>';
  }
  return $output;
}
add_shortcode('cpe-history','cpe_history_select');
```

So, as you can see, I am trying to get just the "id" and "submitDate" fields from the table and display the list of Submit Dates as options in the dropdown list, with the entry's "ID" as the value of the option.
I am logged in as the user with user_id = '1', so there is definitely entries to display, but I'm only getting the initial "Select" option and nothing else.

http://sandbox.graphicdetail.co.nz/cpe-test/

Where have I gone wrong?

PS - Weird thing is, I've created plugins before making similar queries and looping through the results and have not had this sort of issue before. :-/

Comment: What do you get in $cpe_history?

Comment: If you `var_dump($cpe_history)` before the `if` statement, what do you get? Are you sure the data is there?

Comment: @KrupalPanchal we're just going to follow each other around SO and ask the same questions :)

Comment: @disinfor I have not an idea about your comment.

Comment: @KrupalPanchal https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61134029/wordpress-media-uploader-upload-files-font-color-is-white-how-to-change - we are asking the same questions to the OPs, seconds apart.

Comment: @disinfor sorry man, but I have asked before you in both questions. and we are thinking as same way.

Comment: I think there is a language barrier here - I think it's funny that we are thinking the same way. Both times we commented were less than 4 seconds apart! I just thought it was funny that we had commented on two questions in a row, only seconds apart.

Comment: @disinfor may be. after all, we are WordPress developers so thinking like the same way.

Comment: Ok, so, here's something really weird.  If I just put `var_dump($cpe_history)` before the if statement, I get nothing.
BUT, if change the lines:
`$entry_id = $cpe_entry->id;
$entry_date = $cpe_entry->submitDate;`
to:
`$entry_id = $cpe_entry['id'];
$entry_date = $cpe_entry['submitDate'];`
it completely breaks the theme's layout, but it returns this:
`array(6) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#16785 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "16" ["submitDate"]=> string(19) "2020-04-10 14:16:33" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#16959 (2) { ["id"]=> string(2) "15" ["submitDate"]=> string(19) "2020-04-10....` (continues...)

Answer (score 0):

OMG!  I found the problem and I can't believe it was something so simple and obvious!
It was a simple typo!

On the line:

```
$ouput .= '<option value="' . $entry_id . '">' . $entry_date . '</option>';
```

I had simply left the first "t" out of "$output"!  DUH!